# Yii 'Unique' Validator in CFormModel

Tags: php, forms, frameworks, yii, validation

I have this small line of code in Yii Framework:

```
array('username', 'unique', 'attributeName'=> 'username', 'caseSensitive' => 'false'),
```

that gives me an error:

```
RegisterForm and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "tableName".
```

The full RegisterForm.php model:

```
<?php
class RegisterForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $password2;
    public $email;
    public $fullname;
    public $birth;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('username, password, password2, email, fullname, birth', 'required'),

            array('username','length','min'=>3),
            array('username','length','max'=>16),
            array('username', 'filter', 'filter'=>'strtolower'),
            array('username', 'ext.alpha', 'allowSpaces'=>'flase', 'allAccentedLetters'=>'false'),
            array('username', 'unique', 'attributeName'=> 'username', 'caseSensitive' => 'false'),

            array('password', 'length', 'min' =>6),
            array('password', 'length', 'max' =>32),
            array('password', 'compare', 'allowEmpty' => 'false', 'compareAttribute' => 'password2', 'strict' => 'true'),

            array('email', 'length', 'min' =>8),
            array('email', 'length', 'max' =>128),
            array('email', 'email'),

            array('fullname','length','min'=>6),
            array('fullname','length','max'=>64),
            array('fullname', 'ext.alpha', 'allowNumbers'=>'false', 'allAccentedLetters'=>'false'),

            array('birth', 'date', 'allowEmpty'=>'false', 'format'=>'dd/MM/yyyy'),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I guess you somewhere need to tell Yii to which look into for uniqueness.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what I must add or change?

Comment: No I can't but I'm sure that's documented on the Yii website.

Comment: Thank you for giving me non-helpfull, guess-like answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specify an additional property, `className`, in that validator. It should contain the name of the Active Record class whose table should be checked for uniqueness.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUniqueValidator#className-detail